# formatted documents viewable natively on windows and linux

Tags: windows, linux, ms-office, openoffice.org

What should I write my document in if I want them to both to be rich, readable and can be open natively by both linux and windows? I want to write documents and put them in a git repo that could reside on either. Should I use OpenOffice or is there a more lightweight option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the lightweight option would be Rich Text Format (RTF), which can be opened by Linux (OpenOffice, AbiWord, KOffice) and also by Windows (Microsoft Office and also WordPad!). I suggest looking at the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_text_format).

The downside is that it's not as versatile as newer formats (OpenDocument and Microsoft's Docx format). You might want to use OpenDocument format as it is a standarized open format and supported by most office suites. Microsoft Word's format IIRC also standarized, but I don't think support is very good for edge cases in editors other than Microsoft Word. I also don't know how good OpenDocument format is support in Microsoft Word, especially for saving documents.

If you don't need any advanced feature, you could probably settle with RTF =)